# ImageMagick copy the iOS 7 blur effect

Tags: ios7, imagemagick

I have an image that I want to blur like on the iOS 7, see image below:

[image]

I'm not sure what combination of transformations I need to execute to get the same result. I tried something very basic so far (not sure what I'm doing), but the result isn't here:

```
convert {$filename} -filter Gaussian -define filter:sigma=2.5 \
        -blur 0x40 {$newFilename}
```

The above code gets executed by php `exec` function.

Comment: You are going to need some degree of transparency in the top image too, to let the underneath image show through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I take this as `background.png`

[image]

and a plain grey `rgb(200,200,200)` image with a couple of black and white bits and pieces on it, as `foreground.png` since I don't have any iPhone grabs of the slide-up menu thingy

[image]

```
convert background.png                                                   \
   \( +clone -gravity south -crop 360x450+0+0                            \
      -filter Gaussian -define filter:sigma-2.5 -blur 0x40 \)            \
   -composite                                                            \
   \( foreground.png -matte -channel a -fx "(u.r<0.1||u.r>0.9)?1:0.3" \) \
   -composite result.png
```

So, I basically clone the background, and select the bottom part with the `-crop` and blur it, then composite it onto the real background. Then I take the foregound and anywhere it is not black or white, I set it to 30% transparent (so as not to fade the black and white aspects). Then I composite that ontop of the background which by now already has the lower part blurred.

It's probably not 100% but you can diddle around with the numbers and techniques till you achieve Apple-y perfection :-)

[image]

Comment: What about `-fx "(u.r<0.1||u.r>0.9)?1:0.3"`, I actually expect to have the full image blurred and this part that I dont understand is not fullfilling the image

Comment: Furthermore, is it possible to create an image that could be added to the foreground of any other image and make this ios7 effect? That would save much processing time.

Comment: The full image underneath is blurred. I just used `-channel a -fx "..."` to make black and white areas fully opaque and other non-black & white areas only 30% opaque.

Comment: You can use any image you like.